# Is a convergent power series on an open set continuous on that set?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

Question in the title. If a power series $f(x)$ is pointwise (or if this is too weak, uniformly) convergent for every $x$ in an open set $U$ in the reals, is it a continuous function of $x$?

Answer (score 0):

It is even a $\mathcal C^{\infty}$ function.